# PT100 sensor for measuring liquid resin, fully submerged

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, nodemcu, rtd, pt100

**Edited**

Link to Pt100 sensor (That's the best i could do)

https://www.intech.co.nz/products/temperature/mrh.html

Link to ESP8266 datasheet

http://www.handsontec.com/pdf_learn/esp8266-V10.pdf

**Original**

First of all, I am bit of a noob in electronics so i beg your forgiveness.

So i have a question. I have a manufacturing process where we "melt" resin into liquid form and i want to keep track of the temperature (range probably about 100-200 'C ) in an IOT way (Web dashboard, MQTT).

I am thinking of using a 3 wire PT100 with a ESP8266 Nodemcu using wheatstone bridge configuration. The sensor i am thinking of using will look something like this

[image]

Questions:

1. The equipment on which i will be fitting this sensor will be essentially a very large vessel and most probably there will be chances of the whole probe getting submerged in the liquid resin. How this will effect my reading ? Can this create complications or even damage the probe.
2. I am not able to find a circuit schematics for a 3 wire Pt-100. I will be really glad if somebody could literally spoon-fed me on how to make the circuit.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Can you edit your question to add links to the PT100 and ESP8266 datasheets?

Comment: Can't you just find a temperature controller that has a 3-wire input? Building your own is like Brain Surgery Self Taught  Also, using a PT1000 might work if the cable is reasonably short.

Comment: @evildemonic question has been edited. Please check

Comment: @RobertEndl Won't be cost effective. Plus i know a bit or two about the basics. I already have a prototype ready with an IR temperature sensor but it is not helpful for my usecase.

Comment: If you're going to use an industrial PT100, you should also use an industrial PT100 transmitter. Get one that outputs 0-10v, and feed that into your ESP 8266 with a resistor divider. You can also use the 4-20ma version which is more resistant to noise, but the wiring is slightly more complicated.

Comment: MAX31865 or similar IC?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Found this on Bing.  The opamps are obviously r-r and low voltage so they would not be easy to substitute.  You may or may not want to calibrate this depending on the accuracy you need.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0337.pdf